# EC2 Instance connect to RDS accessible through a VPN

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, vpn

I have a Laravel application (API) that I am trying to move to AWS, however, the DB sits privately in AWS and is only accessible to me through a VPN.

The database is an RDS instance.

How can I provide my EC2 instance with access to the RDS Database?

Comment: What do you mean by VPN? Put the RDS & EC2 instances in the same VPCs, configure security groups and they will have access to one another

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary right now if I wanted to access the DB in my local machine I would need to log in to a VPN client.

Comment: What does that have to do with the EC2 instance? Sorry, I'm unclear but what's your actual question? Local access or EC2 access?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary you asked me "What did i mean by VPN?".   Ultimately is EC2 access what I am trying to do.   Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: EC2 access to an RDS instance in the cloud? How do you have Amazon RDS running locally?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary II can connect to an RDS instance locally through a mysql client such as DataGrip etc.   However, it is only accesible through a VPN connection.

Comment: In that case - read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary great, thank you so much.   ill read through it

Comment: In the future, https://serverfault.com/ would be best for this as it's not programming-related but that link should help out - if not, a question there would be better but just wanted to inform you why I'm also going to now vote to close the question. Enjoy using AWS!

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for the hint, wasnt aware of serverfault.  I appreciate it.